# What is the proper way to test a multi-step process in a Java Spring/Hibernate/Maven project?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, testing, tdd

I initially just had a Java Servlet that I needed to unit test.  I wanted to make sure it would handle requests correctly, so I used Spring's MockHttpServletRequest in a jUnit test and that method worked great.  Very simple unit test.

Now, I want to extend the test and I want to do a series of database transactions and mock http servlet requests to simulate users using the system over a period of time.

I guess I could cram all of this into a single unit test but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do since it would violate the spirit of a unit test.

So what is the proper way to test a series of events in a particular order like this?

Here's a stripped down version of what I have so far:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"testContext.xml"}) 
public class servletTest {

//Injected request
@Resource(name="mockTestServletRequest")
MockHttpServletRequest request;

@Test
public void mockRequest() {
    //perform a mock servlet request
}
```

So do I simulate a timeline of events by just adding more methods annotated with @Test above and below the one I have already ?  Am I guaranteed that these methods will be executed in the order listed?

Comment: Do you know [Unit Testing for Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/unittesting-455385.html) by Adam Bien.

Comment: @zellus I just read that article and it is not very applicable to my situation.  I already have a working unit test and I'm trying to figure out what to do now that I want the testing to grow from a simple unit test to a more robust multi-step test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will be an integration test. Take a look at [spring's testing framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html). This means you will start your spring context, and have everything running. You can either use an in-memory database, or a standalone one.

When everything is started, you can inject an instance of a controller of yours and trigger a request, then another one. By default each method is in a transaction, which gets rolled back when the method completes, so don't worry about polluting the database.

Comment: I've added a code snippet and a question below it.  Would multiple methods annotated with <at-symbol>Test be considered a valid integration test?

Answer (score 0):

From a testing mentality perspective, I do agree with you in that a true Unit test should be exactly that: something that tests a single touch point in the code and not beyond that.

Since you are using Maven, you actually have some nice options available.  The recommendation [here on codehaus](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing) might be valuable.  By modularizing your "Integrated Unit Tests", you can assign that to a separate goal and let your more intelligent and orchestrated tests live there.

Another option that I have used is putting an annotation on the test as follows:

```
@IfProfileValue(name="integration", value="true")
```

That allows you to set arguments on whether to run just your true unit tests or integration tests also.

Finally, if you are using a development database and would like to continue doing so, that's fine but if this is a continuous test and you are not rolling back, you might be well served by [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) or another mocking framework.  That really depends on the context of your test though.